# Problem with `&amp;` in Net::HTTP::Get.new

Tags: ruby, http, get, request

I'm using `net/http` in Ruby to send a `GET` request to a web service. The important bit of code is the following:

```
Net::HTTP.start("www.thehost.com") do |http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/api" + ROUTES[sym] + "?" + params)
  resp = http.request req
end
```

`params` is a string which contains key-value pairs in the form `key=val&blag=blorg`. When the response comes in, it turns out to be an error page from the server, which quotes the request URI; instead of `key=val&blag=blorg`, it has `key=val&amp;blag=blorg`. Since when I enter the same address into a web browser with `&` instead of `&amp;`, I get the expected response, I suspect that the escaping of `&` is what's causing the problem. If anyone with more experience disagrees with that, however, feel free to rename my question!

I should note that when I use `http://www.thehost.com/api#{ROUTES[sym]}?#{params}` with `Net::HTTP.get_response`, I get the expected response. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess: are you doing this in Rails, and could its XSS protection/HTML escaping features be the culprit? What happens if you change it to `params.html_safe`?

Since using `#{...}` in one case works, what happens if you do `"/api#{ROUTES[sym]}?#{params}"` instead of concatenating strings with `+`?

Comment: I'm not using Rails; I'll try `html_safe` and get back to you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `html_safe` is a feature of Rails so you won't have any luck with it in that case. Try the other suggestion though.